# Connection to MongoDB Atlas Cluster error

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I am facing an issue connecting to my MongoDB Atlas cluster via Node.js, express and mongoose:

```
{ MongoNetworkError: connection 4 to mongodb-passport-auth-shard-00-00-vp7yg.mongodb.net:27017 closed
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Vishesh\Documents\Projects\nodejs-passport-auth\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:276:9)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:187:15)
    at _handle.close (net.js:606:12)
    at TCP.done (_tls_wrap.js:386:7)
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

Here is the code I used for connecting to my cluster via a Short SRV connection string:

```
mongoose
  .connect(
    'mongodb+srv://myname:mypwd@myapp-vp7yg.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true',
    { useNewUrlParser: true }
  )
  .then(() => console.log("Connected to mongodb..."))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: I never seen this error before, but as per the error text, it look like network error or mongodb port error, try to connect mongodb with different port but before that start mongodb service in different port.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  did you resolve it? for me it was working yesterday and the days before but today it just won't work.  it's defined as transient but it seems permanent to me

Comment: How did you solve this error? I am getting this error with IP whitelisting `0.0.0.0/0`, which discards the solution given below in the answers.

Answer (score 21):

I think you must add your IP address to the **IP Whitelist** in mongoDB.atlas console.

[image: mongoDB.atlass console]

Answer (score 6):

I was getting the same error, here is the solution which resolved this issue.
Add your ip in IP Whitelist.

Hope this hepls.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was getting error

```
MongoNetworkError: connection 1 to ......-shard-00-00.b2zap.mongodb.net:27017 closed
```

even if I added allow access from anywhere in IP whitelist.

After adding my IP address along with allow access from anywhere, it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error

```
MongoServerSelectionError: connection to <ip-addr>:27017 closed
```

And I solved it by going to Security > Network access > IP address and then deleting my IP address and adding a new one allowing access from anywhere.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Update your mongoose.connect method to avoid deprecation warnings

```
mongoose.connect(
  mongoAtlasUri,
  {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
  },
  () => console.log(" Mongoose is connected")
);
```

If you don't know your IP address then you can also this IP address- 0.0.0.0/0 ,but recommended is your own IP address.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced this issue, this is some kind of error from altas side.
Even if you have allowed all the IPs that there is an atlas, it will still be going to throw the same error.

The way to fix it by adding your location IP. You have a specifically whitelist your own IP which is a bit strange considering, that you have allowed all.

That worked for me, I hope this helps others as well.

Answer (score 0):

MondoDB version 4.7.0

I was getting below error in vs code terminal.

error - MongoServerSelectionError: connection  to 3.6.8.93:27017 closed

I got the solution by reconnecting the IP address.

Just delete (if its already there) from
Network access > IP access list > delete the selected IP address

then add it again. Problem solved